# Script organization (all my functions are cluttering my script)

Tags: function, powershell

I have a large script which I'm now cleaning up with the use of functions.
But, I've found that it gets kinda messy to put them all at the top of the script.. I have to scroll past hundreds of lines of codes to get to the script itself..

How do you guys keep your scripts tidy? Do you have your functions in a separate file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Try #Region and #EndRegion

If you use [PowerGUI](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/) script editor you can use regions like this:

```
#region Set of functions A

function foo {
    Write-Host "Just a function"
}

function bar {
    return "Just another function"
}

#endregion
```

When you open the script in PowerGUI script editor the regions will be collapsed so you don't have to scroll to get to the main logic. This also [works in Microsoft ISE.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/11/12/use-regions-in-powershell-ise-2/) Not all script editors honor the region tags though.

## Try dot-sourcing or importing as module

Another way is to externalize your functions either into another script and do what is called dot sourcing `. C:\myfunctions.ps1` or put them in a module file named with a `.psm1` extension and use `Import-Module`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up splitting settings and functions out in two separate files and dot-sourcing them. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I just tried the #region tip in Windows PowerShell ISE and confirm it works there too. They open expanded but you can collapse using CTRL+M

Comment: @RichardEdwards I think that's a V3 feature only.

Answer (score 11):

A useful technique is to put your entire script in a function:

```
#!/bin/sh

main()
{
  # The majority of the code is here
}

foo()
{
  # auxiliary functions go here
}

main "$@" # invoke the main function
```

I just noticed that this question was tagged `powershell`, while the above example is for Bourne.  The technique is probably valid, but the syntax may differ.

Comment: Technique is valid in `powershell`.

Comment: This is a great technique, I use it all the time :-). Keeps your main code at top of file and allows functions to be defined below. Make sure your call to "main" comes after all function definitions. I use this with PowerShell and Python - works in other languages too (William mentioned Bourne Shell).

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up splitting settings and functions out in two separate files and dot-sourcing them. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: The similar answer is in question [Why do I need to have my functions written first in my Powershell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3920032)

Answer (score 10):

## Try Modules

The technique that we have adopted is to make all of our functions loaded via a script module.  We created a folder to hold all of the individual function files and further subdivided them into their appropriate categories. Once we have done that we create a `.psm1` file to tell the module what to load and then add the module path to our PowerShell profile (if not in the default Module location).

### Folder structure

```
Module-Name\
    Subfolder1\
    Subfolder2\
    ...
    Module-Name.psm1
```

#### .psm1 file

Module-Name.psm1 (located underneath a folder with the same name - Required)

```
# Script Module for Company Functions
Function Get-ScriptDirectory {
    # $MyInvocation is an Automatic variable that contains runtime details and
    # we can use this to get information about where the file is run from.
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value
    Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path
}

Get-ChildItem (Get-ScriptDirectory) -Recurse `
    | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "func_*" } `
| %{
    . $_.FullName
}
```

#### Profile file

Microsoft.PowershellISE_profile.ps1 / Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1

```
$LocalLibraries = "C:\Local\Path\On\Disk\"
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";$LocalLibraries"
```

The above code means that you don't have to store the module in the same location as the rest (useful in our case since we use SVN to version and share our stuff with our team).

### Recap

To recap:

- Name function files as "func_{Verb}-{Namespace}{Noun}.ps1"
- Create a top level folder to hold the module psm1 file
- Create subfolders to categorize and hold the functions, i.e. Utilities, Active Directory, Exchange, etc.
- Create your "psm1" file
- Optional: Add additional module location to your profile

We prefix the "ps1" files with "func_" so that when tab-completing the function name, if in the same directory as the file, it will not get confused. In addition, we add the Namespace (company initials, etc) in front so that our function names will not collide with any other added functions.

### Handy reload function

One additional, useful tip, that might come in handy during development is to define an alias, "reload" in our case, that will force the module to reload. This means that once you have changed a file, all you have to do is type that and it will be dot-sourced into memory again with your changes.

```
# Function to reload Module
Function int_ModuleNameModuleLoad {
    Import-Module Module-Name -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host "Module-Name Reloaded"
}

# Set Aliases
If (-not(Get-Alias "reload" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
    New-Alias -Name reload -Value int_ModuleNameModuleLoad -Force
}
```

The reason I use "int_" instead of our normal naming structure is that, this function is located within our profile and I consider it internal and not a full blown function.

I hope this gives you some good ideas, it has worked out great for us so far!

-Adam

Answer (score 4):

One thing to be careful of is scope. This will not work:

```
function main{
    function1
    function2
    function3
 }

function load-functions{
     function function1 {"This is function1"}
     function function2 {"This is function2"}
     function function3 {"This is function3"}
}

load-functions
main
```

The load-functions function will have it's own scope, and the functions it creates will only exist in it's local scope. They will be gone when the function completes and the scope is disposed of.

You'll need run those in the local scope by dot-sourcing the functions like so:
(Note that there's a space between the dot and the function names.)

```
function main{
    function1
    function2
    function3
}

function load-functions{
    function function1 {"This is function1"}
    function function2 {"This is function2"}
    function function3 {"This is function3"}
}

. load-functions
. main
```

It will work if `main` is not run in the local scope, but if you pass arguments to the script you will need to do that for it to use `$args` in the script scope.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is something to def watch out for.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to break the functions out into seperate files and package them up as a module. Then you can simple import the module into the main script.

You do end up with a number of .ps1 file but it does make managing (and testing) each individual function a lot easier.

Webcast on how to do this (it about 1/2 in):

[http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/8773.aspx][1]
  [1]: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/8773.aspx

It also includes a handy module for making modules.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up splitting settings and functions out in two separate files and dot-sourcing them. Thanks for all your help!