# How can I create a PowerShell "main" function?

Tags: powershell

I've used many scripting languages in the past, and am now learning PowerShell. In these other languages I typically define my main logic prior to defining my functions, so someone reading the code will focus on the main logic first. Often this takes the form of creating a "main" function or class at the top of the file, and invoking it at the bottom.

In PowerShell this pattern might look like this:

```
$main = {
    ...
    do-something
    ...
}
function do-something() {
    <function definition here>
}

& $main
```

This works well, but I now want to leverage PowerShell's ability to run code remotely. Since `$main` is a PowerShell `ScriptBlock` object, I [think I] can run that code on a remote machine like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $main -ComputerName whatever;
```

However, the remote machine will know nothing about my function since it is defined outside the scope of `$main`. I can, of course, move the definition of the function into $main, but then I have to put it above the main logic and I'm right back to my first problem.

Is there a common pattern for writing PowerShell scripts where the main logic is in a function or script block at the top of the file, similar to many traditional languages? How do people write complex scripts -- do they always just write them from top-to-bottom, sprinkling in functions as needed at the top?

Someone has flagged this as a possible duplicate of the question [Why do I need to have my functions written first in my Powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3917592/7432). This is not a duplicate of that. I know *why* functions need to be defined first -- I've been programming since C was the cool new language.

What I'm asking for is the pattern for doing so in poweshell, particularly in the context of wanting to be able to run the main code remotely.

Is there a common pattern for putting a `main` block at the top of a powershell script? Powershell syntax and idioms are sufficiently different from more traditional languages, and even many popular modern scripting languages, that the pattern for moving the main logic to the top is not obvious (or maybe it is, but I just haven't found the right examples or documentation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to have my functions written first in my Powershell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917592/why-do-i-need-to-have-my-functions-written-first-in-my-powershell-script)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: I do not believe this is a duplicate -- I know _why_ functions must be declared first. Instead, I'm asking for the common idioms for doing so in powershell, where "main" is a seemingly foreign concept, and while preserving the ability to invoke the code on a remote machine. None of the answers in that other question are suitable answers for this question. I've edited my answer to  hopefully clarify, though this question was adequately answered a couple  years ago.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Scripts are read from the top to the bottom, so you can't use any references before they are initiated. You could however create a script/scriptblock that simulates how programming languages work.

In programming languages like c#, the `main` part is a function. When the app is done loading the necessary parts(like core functions etc.), and event handler calls the main-function to get the party started. With the approach below, you would simulate the same behaviour.

## Invoke-Command with a script block

To use this with `invoke-command`, simply wrap the sample above inside a new scriptblock and use that.

```
$script = {
    #Main-function
    function main {
        #starting helper function
        helper-func
    }

    #Helpers
    function helper-func {
        Write-host "foo"
    }

    #Entry point
    main
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -Scriptblock $script
```

## Invoke-Command with a file

Or save it to a file, and call it that way.

Script.ps1

```
#Main-function
function main {
    #starting helper function
    helper-func
}

#Helpers
function helper-func {
    Write-host "foo"
}

#Entry point
main
```

Usage:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -FilePath '.\Script.ps1'
```

Comment: The first method seems like a very natural (to me...) way to organize code. Why isn't this style more prevalent in the powershell community? Is it that powershell is mostly used for small tasks that don't need local functions?

Comment: Simply because most people don't care about the order I guess. It's more logical to read the code like powershell will read it: from top to bottom. Declare functions early and have call them at the end like I did with the entry point. It makes it easier to understand what's already been declared, and what's not. Especially when it comes to debugging :-) Also, many scripts are simple and don't need lots of structure. The moment you need to create lots of functions, you should consider creating a module instead and create a short script that uses your module-functions/-cmdlets.

Comment: The same idea was suggested in [Why do I need to have my functions written first in my Powershell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3920032)

Answer (score 11):

If you want emulate the "traditional" structure in PowerShell, one way to do that is to use the [`Begin`, `Process` and `End` keywords](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh413265.aspx).

These can appear in any order in the script, but the `Begin` block will always run first, so you can put it at the bottom of your script, and put your function definitions there, and have your main logic at the top of the script in a `Process` or `End` block.

Comment: Ha! Very creative! I do remember reading somewhere a long time ago that you could change the order of the blocks in a begin/process/end statement and thinking to myself "Why would anyone ever want to do that??"  I guess this is why. :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no way to define subroutines after the main code in a script file (`.ps1`), because the code is processed sequentially, and if you call a function before it's defined, you'll get an error.

## Subfunctions

If you want to organize it so that it's clearer which parts are the main code and which parts are subroutines, you *can* declare functions within a function (which also scopes them to the function), but they need to come at the beginning so that they're defined before they're called by the main code:

```
function main {
  param(
    # [...]
  )

  function sub1 {
    # [...]
  }
  function sub2 {
    # [...]
  }

  # [main code, using sub1 and sub2]
}
```

## Modules

The only way I know of to have the subroutines appear after the main function is to use a [PowerShell module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847804.aspx). When you import the module, all the functions defined by it are imported before any of the code is executed.

So when you execute the main function all the subroutines are already defined.

### Modules Background

In case you're not familiar with modules, it's quite simple. Just put all the code into a `.psm1` file (it doesn't have to contain only function definitions, but any other code is executed when the module is imported). Then import it into the session with

```
Import-Module <path to .psm1 file>
```

(Note that you need to add the `-Force` switch to reimport in the same session.)

### Running modules remotely

If you want to run it remotely, this should work:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Import-Module \\<unc path to .psm1 file>; main} -ComputerNam whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer passing a `ScriptBlock` to a remote computer using `Invoke-Command`. That being said, it's perfectly valid to write an entire "start-to-finish" script file, that performs some local task, and then deploy it to the local (and/or remote) computers using the `-File` parameter for `Invoke-Command`.

This code example will dynamically generate a PowerShell script file, and then deploy it to the target systems. This way, you don't have to manually manage multiple script files:

1. A script that performs some task
2. A "deployment" script that wraps script #1

...

```
# 1. Declare script path and contents, and array of target systems
$ScriptPath = '{0}\test\script.ps1' -f $env:SystemDrive;
$ScriptContents = 'Get-Process';
$TargetSystems = 'server01', 'server02', 'server03';

# 2. Create / generate script file, and deploy the script to specified computers
mkdir -Path (Split-Path -Path $ScriptPath -Parent) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Set-Content -Path $ScriptPath -Value $ScriptContents;
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $TargetSystems -File $ScriptPath;
```

If you're like me, and prefer to use a `ScriptBlock`, then the **entire contents** of your script must be contained within the `ScriptBlock`, before you deploy it with `Invoke-Command`.

Here is an example:

```
# 1. Build a ScriptBlock from a PowerShell "Here-String" (multi-line string)
$ScriptBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create(@'
    function Helper1 {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
        )

        begin {
            Write-Host -Object ('{0} was called' -f $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName);
        }
        process { }
        end { }
    }

    function Helper2 {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
        )

        begin {
            Write-Host -Object ('{0} was called' -f $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.InvocationName);
        }
        process { }
        end { }
    }

    function Main {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
        )

        begin {
            Helper1;
            Helper2;
        }
        process { }
        end { }
    }

    # Call Main
    Main;
'@);

# 2. Call the ScriptBlock on localhost
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock;
```

### Output

The output from the above command would look like this:

```
Helper1 was called
Helper2 was called
```