# Passing data between functions with 2 foreach loops

Tags: powershell

The below code doesn't work, I'm trying to pass what could be 1 line, or 1000 lines from the Create-Staff function back up to the Main function. Right now the foreach($user in $new) doesn't match anything even though there is data returned to the Write-Output. So obviously I am doing something wrong.

```
Function Main{
Import a CSV and do stuff here
foreach($row in $import){
#Maybe run this 1 time, maybe run this 1000 times
Create-Staff <variables here>  #Run the other function then come back here
}

foreach($user in $new){
Write-Host "$($user.newperson) $($user.info)"
}    #End Function




Function Create-Staff{
param (
        [Parameter()]

        [string] $lastname,

        [string] $firstname,

        )

--Do Stuff Here--

$new += @([pscustomobject]@{newperson = $newperson;info = $info})
Write-Output -NoEnumerate $new

}
#End Function

Main
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the `Main` function, this isnt python... aside from that, `Create-Staff` has to be defined __before__ the function call, it should be at the top of `Main`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77663166/45375) correctly points out that PowerShell requires functions to be defined *before* they can be called.

  - However, it looks like you were aware of that, and that your aim was to to place the top-level code *first* in your file, so your approach - broken syntax / pseudo code notwithstanding - *is* correct in principle (though not common in PowerShell):

    - Put all top-level code inside a `Main` function, where calls to not-yet-defined auxiliary functions *can* be placed.
    - Follow this with the definition of all auxiliary functions.
    - Finally, invoke the `Main` function as the last statement in your file.
- Judging by your pseudo code, the problem was that *you didn't capture the output from your `Create-Staff ...` call* for later processing, which requires something like `$new = Create-Staff ...`.

  - In the absence of such capturing, the output from `Create-Staff` is simply *passed through* and becomes part of `Main`'s own success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
  - The fact that you used variable `$new` also *inside* your `Create-Staff` suggests that you mistakenly thought that this *function-local* variable definition would also be visible to its caller.

The following is a *PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation* of your code:

```bash
# The main function, containing what is conceptually the top-level code.
# Calls to not-yet-defined functions may be placed inside it.
Function Main {
  # Simulate CSV import.
  @'
LastName,FirstName
Last1,First1
Last2,First2
Last3,First3
'@ | 
    ConvertFrom-Csv |
    New-Staff |
    ForEach-Object {
      # Sample processing.
      "$($_.newperson) $($_.info)"
    }
}  

# Auxiliary function.
Function New-Staff {
  param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [string] $lastname,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [string] $firstname
  )
  process {
    [pscustomobject]@{newperson = "$firstname $lastname"; info = 'info' }
  }
}
  
# Now that all functions are defined,
# invoke the main function.
Main
```

Output:

```bash
First1 Last1 info
First2 Last2 info
First3 Last3 info
```

Note:

- A *single pipeline* is used to do all the processing.
- `Create-Staff` was renamed to `New-Staff`, because `New` is the [approved verb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) for creation of new resources (even though, technically, `New` isn't a *verb*).
- `New-Staff` is defined to accept pipeline input via objects whose property values bind to the parameters of the same name (`[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]`)

  - A pipeline-processing function requires a `process { ... }` block to process each input object.
  - Note that *implicit* output is used from inside that block.

    - No need for [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), whose explicit use is rarely needed; needing `-NoEnumerate` for outputting collections *as a whole* is one use case, but this is best avoided in favor of *object-by-object* output streaming.
- Finally, a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call is used to process each resulting object one by one; note the use of the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the input object at hand.

Comment: The "Main" function was originally there to keep Powershell ISE from spitting out a bunch of code every time I ran it. But everyone has a point, it could go away

Comment: Marking as accepted, extremely educational as well with links and everything.

Comment: I am glad to hear it, @user1983916, thanks for accepting. As for `Main`: even though it isn't common, it is a legitimate way to structure your code, if your preference is to place all your high-level code first.

Answer (score 1):

One of your issues is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918931/15339544), because PowerShell is not a compiled a language you need to **define a function before calling it**.

Example:

```
function Test {
    TestInTest
    function TestInTest { 'hi!' }
}

Test
# Errors with:
# The term 'TestInTest' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function....
```

Second issue is that the parameters from `Create-Staff` (`$lastname` and `$firstname`) are never used in the function, instead you're using undefined variables (`$newperson` and `$info`). Then the code should work properly.

I also advise you against the use this `Main` function, it is completely useless in PowerShell. Up to you if you want to retain it or not.

A simplified example:

```
$csv = @'
lastname,firstname
foo,bar
baz,123
'@

Function Main {
    # function is being defined __before__ the consecutive function call
    Function Create-Staff {
        param (
            [Parameter()]
            [string] $lastname,
            [string] $firstname
        )
        
        # --Do Stuff Here--
        
        [pscustomobject]@{
            newperson = $lastname
            info      = $firstname
        }
    }

    # Import a CSV and do stuff here
    $import = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
    foreach ($row in $import) {
        # Maybe run this 1 time, maybe run this 1000 times
        Create-Staff $row.lastname $row.firstname
        # Run the other function then come back here
    }
}

Main
```

Comment: I believe I have the functions defined first already right? Powershell reads both functions (there are actually more) before I tell it to run the "Main" function. But everyone has a point, the "Main" function isnt' really needed. It was originally there to prevent Powershell studio from spitting out a bunch of code every time I ran it

Comment: @user1983916 thats correct but the inner functions (the functions within functions) are not parsed until the outer function runs, like it is demonstrated with the `Test` and `TestInTest` example, so, order matters in PowerShell